# Как убрать расширение php и знак "?" в адресной строки браузера

Tags: .htaccess

Добрый день помогите с настройкой файла .htaccess. Я не могу убрать знак доллар с адресной строки.

```
<a href="gallery/load?/zalivka></a>
```

Здесь gallery домен на локально сервере Open Server, load это файл load.php(Мне удалось убрать расширение php) Но я не могу убрать знак ?, когда я его убираю, страница стает недоступной.
Собственно от файл .htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .?.php[? ].$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: Вопросительный знак не является знаком доллара.. Насколько мне известно.

Comment: Тут главное понять, что вы не убираете тот же `.php`, а наоборот, добавляете то, чего не было в запросе.

Comment: Извините, ошибся, мне нужно чтобы расширения .php? не было видно а адресной строке (http://gallery/load.php?/zalivka)  а нужно (http://gallery/load/zalivka)

Comment: То есть, запрос будет `gallery/load/zalivka`, а вы хотите, чтобы апач вызвал скрипт `load.php` с `$_GET['/zalivka'] = null;`?

Comment: Я использую обычную ссылку, для навигации.

Comment: <?php while ($show = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezult)) {?>
      <a href="load.php?/<?php echo $show['url']; ?>"><?php echo $show["title"]; ?></a>
     <?php } ?>

Comment: Что-то вроде этого? `RewriteRule ^(.*)(/[^/]*)/?$ $1.php?$2 [L]`

Comment: Спасибо, работает)))

Comment: Только от почему-то скрипты перестают работать, вы с этим сталкивались?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Неожиданный токен <
Uncaught SyntaxError: Neozhidannyy token <

Comment: RewriteCond нужны нормальные, он ведь и статику так ломает

Comment: `Neozhidannyy token` - интересный у вас браузер/парсер =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут главное понять, что вы не убираете тот же .php, а наоборот, добавляете то, чего не было в запросе.
Т.е. есть то, что мы пишем в ссылке на странице(нечто симпатичное) и то, как это должен интерпретировать сервер.

Для преобразования ссылки вида `/gallery/load/zalivka` в запрос `/gallery/load.php?/zalivka` мы разделим исходный запрос на 2 части: имя скрипта, и параметр-ссылка:

- параметр-ссылка: `(/[^/]*)/?$` слеш и некоторое количество не-слешей в конце строки, в самом конце опционально может быть ещё слеш.
- остальное начало запроса: `^(.*)`

Итого:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # не применяем правило к существующим файлам
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/[^/]*)/?$ $1.php?$2 [L]
```

К имени скрипта(`$1` - первые скобки) добавляем расширение(.php), знак вопроса и параметр(`$2` - вторые скобки)